# Relation between variance of all elements and variance of all elements except zero

Tags: probability

We have **n** values: $\\x_1, x_2, x_3 ... x_n$, and **m** of them are **not** equal to zero.

---

Let $ E(x) $ be the avarage of all values: $ E(x) = $$1 \over n $$ \sum x_i  $

Let $ E^\prime(x) $ be the avarage of all **non-zero** values: $ E(x) = $$1 \over m $$ \sum x_i  $

Let $V(x)$ be the variance of all elements:
$ V(x) = $$1 \over n $$ \sum (x_i-E(x))^2  $

Let $V(x\ | \ x \ne 0)$ be the variance of all **non-zero** element:
$ V(x\ | \ x \ne 0) = $$1 \over m $$ \sum (x_i-E^\prime(x))^2  $

---

Is there any algebraic relation between $V(x)$ and $V(x\ | \ x \ne 0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there are virtually no constraints if you not not have more information such as the the means with and without the zeros

Obviously you cannot have $U$ or $V$ negative. Nor can you have $V$ zero and $U$ positive with a finite population. Meanwhile having both $U$ and $V$ zero can be satisfied with the whole population taking a single nonzero value, and having $U$ zero and $V$ positive can be achieved with a population with the two values $2\sqrt{V}$ and zero

Otherwise, you can find an example for all $U$ and $V$ by considering a population size $n$ with the two values $\sqrt{\frac{n^2V-2nU}{2n-4}}+\sqrt{U}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{n^2V-2nU}{2n-4}}-\sqrt{U}$, plus $n-2$ copies of zero

These provide the required population variances, at least when $n \ge \frac{2U}{V}$, i.e. $U\le \frac{2V}{n}$, which is not much of a constraint since you do not seem *a priori* to know $n$.  Other examples are also possible

---

Your later edit added that you might know the means as well as the variances, overall and without the zeros. You can then say

$$n=mE[X\mid X\not=0]$$
$$nE[X^2]=mE[X^2\mid X\not=0]$$
$$Var(X)= E[X^2]-E[X]^2$$
$$Var(X\mid X\not=0)= E[X^2\mid X\not=0]-E[X\mid X\not=0]^2$$

and so you can eliminate $n$ and $m$ to state the conditional variance in terms of the the other three

$$Var(X\mid X\not=0)=  \frac{E[X\mid X\not=0]}{E[X]}Var(X) + E[X\mid X\not=0]\,E[X] -E[X\mid X\not=0]^2$$

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see my edit

Comment: @align: knowing the means makes a big difference - see my addition